# inputAccessoryView not working or formatting properly

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitoolbar, uidatepicker, inputaccessoryview

I am setting up a `datepicker` in place of a keyboard for a `UITextField` and the `UIToolbar`. I want to be able to close the `accessoryView`, but it isn't operating as it should. Although I am pressing the <kbd>Done</kbd> button,  the action method isn't being called and the toolbar formatting is not the color I want.

`[UIColor defaultAppColor]` is supposed to be a shade of red, and it isn't appearing anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor universalGreyColor];

UIToolbar *dobToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dateSelected:)];
doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor universalActionColor];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSeparator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
dobToolbar.items = @[flexibleSeparator, doneButton];
dobToolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:33.0/255.0 alpha:1];
dobToolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor defaultAppColor];

[dobToolbar setShadowImage:[UIImage new] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny];

//dobToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

self.dob.inputAccessoryView = dobToolbar;

self.dob.inputView = datePicker;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your tool bar might not have a frame at this point.  Try adding:

```
[dobToolbar sizeToFit];
```

And that should get your bar button to start working.

If you want your toolbar to be `defaultAppColor`, then try setting it to the `barTintColor` property, not `backgroundColor`.

Comment: You could find other ways to set your frame too like `initWithFrame:`